# How to combine a Numpy array of shape [N,4] with one of shape [M] to get an array of shape [N*M,4]

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, one with shape [N,4], eg:

```
x1= [[1,2,3,4],
     [2,3,4,5],
     [7,3,2,1]]
```

and one with shape [M], eg::

```
x2=[1,2,3,4]
```

I would like to get a final array with shape [N*M,4] where, if c is a constant:

```
x3= [[1+c,2+x2[0],3-c,4-x2[0]],
     [2+c,3+x2[0],4-c,5-x2[0]],
     [7+c,3+x2[0],2-c,1-x2[0]],
     [1+c,2+x2[1],3-c,4-x2[1]],
     [2+c,3+x2[1],4-c,5-x2[1]],
     [7+c,3+x2[1],2-c,1-x2[1]],
     [1+c,2+x2[2],3-c,4-x2[2]],
     [2+c,3+x2[2],4-c,5-x2[2]],
     [7+c,3+x2[2],2-c,1-x2[2]],
     [1+c,2+x2[3],3-c,4-x2[3]],
     [2+c,3+x2[3],4-c,5-x2[3]],
     [7+c,3+x2[3],2-c,1-x2[3]]]
```

I can loop through the rows in the first, and do the operation, but is there, as I suspect, a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Is is always going to the the case that the second column uses subtraction and the other addition? Or, is there some rule to be followed regarding the sign?

Comment: Actually the 1st and 3rd entries will have a constant added and subtracted respectively, the 2nd and third will have the x2 array added and subtracted. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following using the [`tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) and [`repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) functions:

```py
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array(
    [[1,2,3,4],
     [2,3,4,5],
     [7,3,2,1]]
)

x2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

# array of signs of sum
signmask = np.array([1, -1, 1, 1])

# tile x1
x1t = np.tile(x1, (len(x2), 1))

# repeat and reshape x2
x2t = np.repeat(x2, 3 * 4).reshape(4 * 3, 4) * signmask

print(x1t + x2t)
```

**Update**: with the edited question, you could do similar to above but with:

```py
c = 10  # some constant

signmask = np.array([1, 1, -1, -1])

x2t = np.repeat(x2, 3 * 4).reshape(4 * 3, 4)

# set required columns to constants
x2t[:, np.r_[0, 2]] = c

print(x1t + x2t * signmask)
```

Answer (score 1):

The result you're looking for can be achieved by using a combination of [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html#numpy.tile) and [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy-repeat).

```py
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [7, 3, 2, 1]])
x2 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
c = 8

# Expand x2 to reach  of size NxM, 4
x2_expanded = np.repeat(x2[:, None], x1.shape[0], axis=0).repeat(x1.shape[1], axis=1)

# Set column to constant and add sign
x2_expanded[:, [0, 2]] = c
x2_expanded *= np.array([1, 1, -1, -1])

# Sum with tiled x1
x3 = np.tile(x1, (x2.shape[0], 1)) + x2_expanded
```

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily go 3D to benefit from broadcasting.

First assuming you don't want to swap the signs:

```
x3 = (x1[None]+x2[:,None,None]).reshape(-1, x1.shape[1])
```

Now, you can use the same logic to craft an array with your constant:

```
c = 100
x3 = (x1[None]+np.vstack(list(np.broadcast(c, x2, c, x2)))[:,None,:]
     ).reshape(-1, x1.shape[1])
```

Output:

```
array([[101,   3, 103,   5],
       [102,   4, 104,   6],
       [107,   4, 102,   2],
       [101,   4, 103,   6],
       [102,   5, 104,   7],
       [107,   5, 102,   3],
       [101,   5, 103,   7],
       [102,   6, 104,   8],
       [107,   6, 102,   4],
       [101,   6, 103,   8],
       [102,   7, 104,   9],
       [107,   7, 102,   5]])
```